# Check input for number

Tags: java, exception, int, validation

I'm new to Java. I created this code in order to check input field for string or number.

```
try {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException nFE) {
    // If this is a string send error message
    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
            "  " + findValue + " must be number!", null));
}
```

How I can create the same check for number but using just `if(){}` without try-catch?

Comment: Why don't you want the try/catch?  You're already using exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `pattern` with `String#matches` method: -

```
String str = "6";

if (str.matches("[-]?\\d+")) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

`"[-]?\\d+"` pattern will match any sequence of `digits`, preceded by an optional `-` sign.

`"\\d+"` means match one or more digits.

Comment: +1 I always just tried to parse it to number. This is a lot more elegant!

Comment: @RNJ.. In case of `integers` yeah, it's pretty much elegant.

Comment: Neat, but why allow plus sign?  "+6" would throw an exception.

Comment: @whiskeyspider.. Oh, thank you so much. Will edit. Didn't notice that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to explicitly catch the the exception then you'd be better off making a helper method.

eg.

```
public class ValidatorUtils {

    public static int parseInt(String value) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
            "  " + findValue + " must be number!", null));
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int someNumber = ValidatorUtils.parseInt("2");
    int anotherNumber = ValidatorUtils.parseInt("nope");

}
```

This way you don't even need to bother with an if statement, plus your code doesn't have to parse the integer twice.